# How to add authorization in Azure function app to stop unauthorized access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am very new to Azure, I have created a function app and I want to add authorization for accessing the function app.

I have added read about Identity provider, which can be used to restrict the access based on token audience but to grant access i need to white list the audience and while doing this function app restarts which means on any customer onboarding function app will be restarted.

Is there any alternative approach on the same? also any heads up on how to get customer on boarding will really help.

Comment: is it an api ? a webapp you re trying to build ? really depends Oauth2 should be the way to go tbh.

Comment: This should get you started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization.

Comment: I am trying to create a REST endpoint

Comment: will it be consume by users / apps ? you dont need to configure the auth multiple time, you just need to grant permissions to users / apps later on but it does not require a restart

Comment: as of now it will be consumed by user by can be extended to apps as well

Answer (score 0):

You can fairly use “function keys” to restrict somebody to call your function out of the blue. There’re different type of those keys for different usage. Please see below guidance in documentation:

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts?tabs=v4)